# Semantics of F# statement

Tags: syntax, f#, function, semantics, currying

Can someone describe this F# expression to me?

```
val augment: GameGrid -> points -> unit
```

What does the `val` keyword mean?

Is it true that usually **`type -> type`** indicates a function that returns the specified type? So does **`type -> type -> type`** indicate a function that returns a function that returns the specified type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The 'val' bit is not an expression; offhand I think it can appear in three different contexts:

- the output of FSI (F# interactive REPL), describing the inferred type of a binding
- in a signature (.fsi) file, describing the type of a let-bound module value
- in a struct/class definition ('explicit' syntax), to define an instance variable

and none of those are technically expression contexts.)

As for the type, indeed

```
A1 -> A2 -> R
```

means a function that takes an A1, and returns a function that takes an A2 and returns an R.  The arguments are curried, and it may do you well to read e.g.

[F# function types: fun with tuples and currying](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!169.entry)

which describes currying and partial application in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

How did you get this output? In FSI?

Val just indiciates a definition of a value.

E.g. if you wrote the following in C#

```
private void Foo(int i);
```

you would write this in F#

```
val Foo : int -> unit
```

Concerning `type -> type -> type`: This is a function with two parameters (type) returning `type´

E.g.

```
let plus a b = a + b
```

has got signature `int -> int -> int`.

Your idea with a function that returns a function is actually correct. This is a very interesting technique in many functional languages called [currying](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Higher_Order_Functions#Currying_and_Partial_Functions)

Comment: Yes, it came from an FSI file.